# PHP & MQTT - Publish and subscribe in same function

Tags: php, laravel, mqtt

Is there a way to make this work..

I'm trying to publish a 'PING' request to a device, and then subscribe to another channel and wait for the 'PONG' response. Here's the code:

```php
public function ping(Request $request)
{
    $device = Device::find($request->id);

    if ($device) {
        //Listen on laravel_device_DEVICEID
        $listen_topic = 'laravel_device_' . $device->device_id;
        $result = [];
        $mqtt = MQTT::connection();
        $mqtt->subscribe($listen_topic, function (string $topic, string $message) use ($mqtt, &$result) {
            $result['topic'] = $topic;
            $result['message'] = $message;
            $mqtt->interrupt();
        }, 0);

        $mqtt->loop(true, true);

        //Submit PING message
        $topic = $device->device_id;
        $message = json_encode([
            'type' => 'ping',
            'device_id' => $device->device_id
        ]);

        $mqtt = MQTT::connection();
        $mqtt->publish($topic, $message);
        $device->last_ping_response = 2;
        $device->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm so free to copy my response from the original question in the [`php-mqtt/laravel-client` repository](https://github.com/php-mqtt/laravel-client/issues/13).

---

Yes, it is possible and a fairly common thing to do as well. The pattern is called RPC (*Remote Procedure Call*).

Your code already looks quite good, the only issue is the order of `subscribe()`, `publish()` and `loop()`. Subscribing first is cruicial, since you do not want to miss a response before your subscription goes through. This part is correct already. But you may start the loop only *after* publishing the request, otherwise the `publish()` is never reached (because the loop does not exit by itself, only when it receives a message).

Here is the updated piece of code of yours, with some best practices added in. I assumed the response message is what you want to save as `$device->last_ping_response`:

```php
use PhpMqtt\Client\MqttClient;
use PhpMqtt\Client\Exceptions\MqttClientException;

public function ping(Request $request)
{
    $device = Device::find($request->id);

    // Exit early if we have no device to ping. Doing it this way round,
    // we save one level of identation for the rest of the code.
    if ($device === null) {
        return;
    }

    // Prepare all data before connecting to the broker. This way, we do not waste
    // time preparing data while already connected.
    $subscribeTopic = "laravel_device_{$device->device_id}";
    $publishTopic = $device->device_id;
    $request = json_encode([
        'type' => 'ping',
        'device_id' => $device->device_id,
    ]);
    
    try {
        $mqtt = MQTT::connection();

        // Ensure we are ready to receive a response to the request
        // we are going to send.
        $mqtt->subscribe(
            $subscribeTopic,
            function (string $topic, string $message) use ($mqtt, $device) {
                // Update the device based on the response.
                $device->last_ping_response = $message;
                $device->save();

                $mqtt->interrupt();
            },
            MqttClient::QOS_AT_LEAST_ONCE
        );
        
        // Here we register a timeout using a loop event handler.
        // The event handler is passed the elapsed time
        // the loop runs already (in seconds).
        // We do this because in case the receiver of our request is offline,
        // we would be stuck in a loop forever.
        $mqtt->registerLoopEventHandler(
            function function (MqttClient $client, float $elapsedTime) {
                // After 10 seconds, we quit the loop.
                if ($elapsedTime > 10) {
                    $client->interrupt();
                }
            }
        );

        // Send the request. We use QoS 1 to have guaranteed delivery.
        $mqtt->publish($publishTopic, $request, MqttClient::QOS_AT_LEAST_ONCE);

        // Wait for a response. This will either return when we receive
        // a response on the subscribed topic, or after 10 seconds
        // due to our registered loop event handler.
        $mqtt->loop();

        // Always disconnect gracefully.
        $mqtt->disconnect();
    } catch (MqttClientException $e) {
        \Log::error("Pinging device failed.", [
            'device' => $device->id,
            'exception' => $e->getMessage(),
        ]);
    }
}
```